# why the css style did not working ? ( Laravel )

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-8

I want to ask something because I don't quite understand the file.

I want to create a Login/Register for a User and I found a tutorial to create the login and register I want.

Here tutorial website link: https://medium.com/geekculture/customize-the-login-and-register-page-for-user-admin-in-laravel-v8-9e42127d0185

and also GitHub complete file: https://github.com/sgwebfreelancer/laravel_auth_tutorial

The tutorial has provided a complete file with the login/register for the User and also the Admin Panel.

But there are some problems where the CSS file does not seem to work and the login and register design becomes empty. It should have like a picture. Below me as well as how login and register should be:

[image: login page]

[image: Register page]

in this tutorial it should be like this :

[image: real design login page]
[image: real design register page]

So how to solve this problem? Do you have any problem with css or app.blade.php file?

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-scroller">
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper full-page-wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper d-flex align-items-center auth auth-bg-1 theme-one">
            <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
                    <div class="auto-form-wrapper">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label">Email</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="email" type="email"
                                        class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"
                                        value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="label">Password</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="password" type="password"
                                        class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
                                        required autocomplete="current-password">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn btn-block">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-flat mt-0">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"
                                            {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Keep me signed in
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="text-small forgot-password text-black"
                                        href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-block text-center my-3">
                                <span class="text-small font-weight-semibold">Not a member ?</span>
                                <a href="register.html" class="text-black text-small">Create new account</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
</div>
<!-- container-scroller -->
```

@endsection

register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container-scroller">
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper full-page-wrapper">
        <div class="content-wrapper d-flex align-items-center auth register-bg-1 theme-one">
            <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
                    <h2 class="text-center mb-4">{{ __('Register') }}</h2>
                    <div class="auto-form-wrapper">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="name" type="text"
                                        class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"
                                        value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus
                                        placeholder="Name">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    @error('name')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="email" type="email"
                                        class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"
                                        value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="password" type="password"
                                        class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
                                        required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="**********">

                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                        name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password"
                                        placeholder="**********">
                                    <div class="input-group-append">
                                        <span class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="mdi mdi-check-circle-outline"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-flat mt-0">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" checked> I agree to the terms
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-btn btn-block">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-block text-center my-3">
                                <span class="text-small font-weight-semibold">Already have and account ?</span>
                                <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="text-black text-small">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    </div>
    <!-- page-body-wrapper ends -->
</div>
<!-- container-scroller -->
```

@endsection

css file asset/css/demo_1/style.css you guys see from here

https://github.com/sgwebfreelancer/laravel_auth_tutorial/blob/main/public/assets/css/demo_1/style.css

layouts/app.blade.php file you guys can see from here

https://github.com/sgwebfreelancer/laravel_auth_tutorial/blob/main/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

in my console, I saw my CSS not load it.

[image]

Comment: "_it is have any problem with css or app.blade.php file ?_" Hard to tell without seeing your css or your blade file. Please [edit] your question and post those

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Check in the console for errors - most likely your CSS file is not loading, and that will tell you why.

Comment: Can you paste the html from your head section? And: are you run `npm install && npm run dev`?

Comment: already put code

Comment: hello @brombeer  i'm already put the code

Comment: hello @Justinas i'm already edit my post

Comment: remove public path
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/assets/css/shared/style.css') }}">
replace to 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/shared/style.css') }}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **layouts.app**, line 15, you have to change :

```
href="{{ asset('public/assets/css/shared/style.css')
```

to

```
href="{{ asset('/assets/css/shared/style.css')
```

Comment: okay thank you so much. it's working